# Accessibility iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I am reusing one view controller for two different screens. when user navigates to the view controller first time voice over speaks the default title(first title). When navigation item title changes voice over not speaks the title.

How can I turn on voice over to speak by default, when navigation item title changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer. Before changing the title I called,

```
 UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification,nil)
```

working perfectly fine.